# How often can I post questions to ELL?

Tags: discussion

For example I asked one question.
[What does 'what sticks' mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7445/how-to-understand-the-what-sticks)

And it seems a little small.  What if I have ten such questions?  Should I combine them or update/edit them into one post?  Or ten posts?

Do you mind if many of the questions showing up in the first page are all asked by the same person?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the last sentence?

Comment: @snailboat aha, for example, I post 20 such questions in succession in 10 minutes ?

Comment: You might have trouble coming up with a question, [*thoroughly researching it*](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), then documenting your research, explaining why you couldn't figure out the problem, and so on . . . every thirty seconds.

Comment: As far as I know, however, you cannot post more than six questions for day, but now I'm not able to give the source where I read this rule, sorry.

Comment: Interesting. There is a limit then! When I suggested such a thing I got 7 down votes on Meta! Admittedly I had a list of other features and people voted on the least popular one. Which brings us nicely to HyperGroups' dilemma. It is better not to group more than two questions at a time, if you can find a coherent way of linking the two, I think nobody would object. Three or more questions in a single post, and people will complain that you ought to do your research first. You might get down-votes because one of the questions may appear to be banal, off topic, unclear etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have no objection to multiple successive questions from the same person. We *do* have an objection to questions that don't show any research effort. If you can post 20 questions that are well-written, show research effort, and are on-topic, then we really don't care whether it took you 10 minutes or 10 days. (Keep in mind, though, that it's extremely unlikely that a question that took 30 seconds to write is going to be of acceptable quality...)

Edit: Thanks to Carlo_R's memory, I've looked it up, and apparently there is a limit: six questions per day. [Why are we limited to six questions per day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127567/why-are-we-limited-to-six-questions-per-day)

Edit2: Nevermind, scratch that, apparently the limits only apply to the "trilogy" sites (stackexchange, superuser, and serverfault).

Comment: I agree. Post questions like you'd sip wine. Give us a couple of good ones, and then, while we're thinking about those gems, the O.P. can be researching and planning the next couple. Why rush through 20 questions in a week? Why not draw them out over a month?

Comment: The 6-question limit is actually [only valid on the Trilogy sites (SO, SF, SU)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89241/187816). The rest of this is completely spot-on, though. Just because the system doesn't *prevent* you from asking more than 6 questions in a day doesn't mean it isn't a good guideline. Put effort into your questions and you're all set :) +1!

Comment: I'm upvoting because the first paragraph reflects exactly what I think. But arguably the point about a 6-a-day limit shouldn't be there at all, since apparently it *doesn't* apply to ELL anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, sorry, edited. (I'd been meaning to, but kept forgetting.)

Comment: @ Martha: I think it's unlikely anyone could and would ask dozens of questions per day. But as you imply, if someone did, ***provided*** each question was acceptable on its own merits, that's all that matters.

Answer (score -4):

Suggestion: maybe think of a way to combine your five/more questions as one well written post or as a followup in the same topic. One topic per day from a poster is reasonable. Two or three is also fine as long as they are well written. I generally think people who are posting too many questions (five or more) as spammers and wasting everyone’s time. It’s unhealthy for a forum to just have one person posting all the questions. Diversity is important. I benefit more from questions by many users on many topics with diverse writing styles. Don’t know if there’s already a rule on this.

Comment: I would not encourage combining questions, unless they're very closely related, and/or if they're really just multiple examples of the same question. The SE sites are not set up to deal with multiple different questions in the same post. For example, imagine a response that correctly answers one of the sub-questions, but gives an incorrect answer for another, and totally ignores a third. Do you vote it up? Down? Flag it as "not an answer"? If others vote it up, is it because of the correct answer, or because they don't know the incorrect answer is incorrect? It just gets too confusing.

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend combining unrelated things together. But I’ve seen some users having only certain types of questions (specific grammar topic). Maybe have some flexibility for those cases.

Comment: I disagree with a lot of this answer, but I do agree that diversity is important, and that it's not a bad idea to make a concientious effort to avoid monopolizing the board for a day.